# opengl - glDrawElements not drawing triangles

Tags: c++, opengl

Im trying to create an OBJ parser which reads the file and send the vertices to opengl. I am using glDrawElements to draw the model but it looks like it is not compose of triangles. You can look below for my code on how am I doing this. Code snippet is just a sample. Please take note of the indices count is different on what model I am loading.

```
GLuint vbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ff);
glVertexAttribPointer(ff, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbid);
GLuint buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(GLshort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Here's the output I am getting. 
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Yr6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code

```
glDrawElements(GL_LINE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

you are using GL_LINE_STRIP which isn't what you want if your data contains triangles. What you want in this case is GL_TRIANGLES which will give you the expected behavior.

Also, I don't know if this is just a typo but in your glDrawElements call you pass GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT while when initializing the element buffer you pass in sizeof(GLshort), not GLushort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was supposed to be GLushort. Regarding the primitive type to be used, I was wondering how can I get an output of the same model in using line_strip? I just like to verify if the rendering of the vertices is correct because when using GL_TRIANGLES, I can get a correct output with this model.

Comment: The reason you aren't getting the same result is that the last vertex from one triangle is being connected to the first in the next.

Comment: But how should I pass the vertices? Is there any standard way to do this? Do I need to rearrange all of them including the indices? I am too confuse now and I am new to opengl. I hope you can help me on this.

Comment: Using lines, there will be no way to get the result you want because it doesn't know what is inside the polygon. It can only create a line the size of the width set by glLineWidth. In order to help you further, I need to know what you want as an output: either the exact output of GL_TRIANGLES or the same with a wireframe effect, in which case you can use GL_TRIANGLES and use the function glSetPolyginMode with the parameters GL_FRONT_AND_BACK and GL_LINE, and to set it back to normal replace GL_LINE with GL_FILL. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml

Comment: I would just want to have first a wireframe effect to check if it draws correctly. My hint why I am getting this kind of output is probably i am sending an incorrect order of indices. What I do is I just send directly the indices to glDrawElements without touching its order. The glSetPolygonMode is helpful so that I don't need to draw another model with GL_LINES. But still, I can't get a proper output.

Comment: So do you want a wireframe next to the filled version? What is the "proper output"

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is the expected output for the same model. [link] (https://imgur.com/o6dBq35). As you can see, the bottom part of the model is drawn with triangles even it is in a wireframe effect. I am using this online OBJ model viewer for reference of the correct output [link] (http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/ObjViewer)

Comment: So the image you posted above is from the OBJ viewer?

Comment: Yes. And the image I posted on my original post is the one I get from my parser. The bottom part of the model is the difference which is their output is much more cleaner and compose of triangles.

Comment: And what do you get if you use GL_TRIANGLES instead of GL_LINE_STRIP?

Comment: GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP with glSetPolygonMode() is this one https://imgur.com/EejJIw0,dvFxxE9, the second image will be without the PolygonMode. Same output with GL_TRIANGLES

Comment: Sorry. This is the output with PolygonMode enabled in GL_TRIANGLES. https://imgur.com/qye951r. As you can see it is the same now as with online viewer. But why it has different output with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP? Anything I miss?

Comment: It's how the indexing works. GL_TRIANGLES works by every three elements in the element array buffer are strung together to get a triangle. GL_LINE_STRIP works by drawing a line between each vertex in the element array buffer, sequentially, not unlike connect the dots. In order to emulate this, you must use GL_LINES because the last vertex in one triangle will be connected to the first in the next, which GL_TRIANGLES doesn't do. To do this, the elements would turn from 0, 1, 2 with GL_TRIANGLES to 0, 1,   1, 2    2, 3 because GL_LINES groups the elements into pairs.

Comment: And with the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP is has also to do with indexing? Like 0,1,2,3,4 it would be 0,1,2 then 2,1,3 then 2,3,4? I am right with this? Seems like I am getting the logic behind the primitives. Haha I just want to verify the STRIPS primitives if it works like that.

Comment: The first parameter in glDrawElements is basically a hint to OpenGL on how your indices are laid out, which means it effects the rasterization of the primitives (lines, faces etc.)

Comment: So the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS are laid out as I mention above? Or it has other proper indexing?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For questions like that, google is a great resource. Your first reflex shouldn't be SO. Five seconds on google rendered me [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_strip)

Comment: I found out about that I just verified if that is correct as other tutorials does not say anything about that. Anyways, thanks for the help :)